# During which phase of building a binary is activation record defined?

Tags: c++, c, activation-record

Is it during a pre-processing or compilation stage, say on gcc? Is it different on other compilers?

Comment: How stack frame can be built during preprocessing? Preprocessing does just macro expansion, and preprocessor output is source text.
Seems you don't really know what are you asking about.

Comment: What don't you undestand? In c++ there is a concept of actication record -- read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_record#Structure-- and I would like to find when it is being constructed by GCC compiler.

Comment: @enigma Calm down and read my comment. You don't understand either what is activation record (aka call stack frame) or what is preprocessing.

Comment: cool, then why don't you explain it instead of judging my question?

Comment: @enigma That's wasn't your question. Ask questions like "What happens during preprocessing?" or "What is activation record?". I just trying to explain to you that your question makes no sense and you better delete it. Stack frame is created at program startup so it is neither preprocessing nor compilation.

Comment: @qrdl: my question was and is  "During which phase of building a binary is activation record constructed" I really do not see anything wrong with it...aghhhh

Comment: @engima Activation record isn't constructed during building of binary (I explained it to you above), so your question makes no sense. Take a deep breath a think before posting ;)

Comment: Edit the question to clarify you mean when the record is defined rather than instantiated ( whether on a stack or elsewhere ).

Comment: @Peter Good point. Done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack frame is created at runtime by modifying the stack register of the processor (`esp` for Intel x86).

The compiler only dump specific instructions to reserve space on the stack at each function call. This space is then recovered when the function exits.

Comment: Except some languages don't use a stack for instantiating the activation records at runtime, and some compilers have a data structure which represents the content of the activation record which is created during translation and then the code is generated from the constructed record.

Comment: And some processors (esp. SPARC) use sliding register windows for the activation record - it's important to understand that a simple description of how it could be done will leave out all complex real-world optimizations.